# git "pre-push" hook stdin is empty

Tags: bash, git, githooks

I'm trying to create a pre-push hook that will prevent the user from pushing to a branch other than the one they're on.

Based on the the pre-push.sample (and various threads I've read) it looks like I should be able to read which local branch I am pushing and the remote one I'm pushing to via stdin with:

```
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
...
done
```

However when I do this, `local_ref` and the other variables are empty (even when running the unedited sample hook, it never enters the loop).

Is there some configuration or other step I need to do to access the variables at stdin?

I'm using `git version 2.17.1`

Comment: Can you show us (a) exactly what your `pre-push` script looks like and (b) how you're resting it? The `pre-push` script does receive that information on `stdin`; without more context that loop looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

From running into this same issue myself I believe you're seeing the same thing I was, if the push contains no changes i.e. when you run git push you see "Everything up-to-date" then the input line from stdin will be blank, there has to be some change being pushed for that line to be populated.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your hook is called at all.
That means:

- its name shoud be `pre-push` (no `.sample`)
- it should be executable (unless you are on Windows, in which case it is executable by default)

Comment: Hooks can be used directly, as you are trying to do, or using a management tool. Sometimes hooks can get complicated to code. You can check https://githooks.com/ for some lecture and options.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you run commands before the loop that already read stdin. In my case, I had some commands from git lfs in my pre-push script. I had to move the loop *before* that command.

```
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/pre-push'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```